# How to get Oid of column from the given datatype name

Tags: c++, postgresql

I am implementing a function to get Oid from the given datatype name.
The datatype name is gotten from remote server (ex: MySQL, Postgres, GridDB)

This function like below:

```
static Oid
get_oid_from_type(char *column_type)
{
    if (strcmp(column_type, "INT") == 0 ||
        strcmp(column_type, "INTEGER") == 0 ||
        strcmp(column_type, "int4") == 0)
    {
        return INT4OID;
    }

    // TODO: There is a lot of types need to add here
    // I do not know how many data type is enough
}
```

I do not know how many data type is enough to add in this function.
So is there a function of Postgresql can do that?

I think maybe there is a function relate to TYPENAMENSP in Postgresql, that can help me, but I have not found it yet.

Comment: See [pg_typeof](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-info.html) and perhaps also the referenced information.

Comment: @Belayer
Thank you, in my understanding, pg_typeof function gets name of data type from Oid, but I need an opposite function, that gets Oid from name of data type.

Comment: Yes, that is what does. Sorry I misinterpreted what you were asking. But AFAIK there is nothing that gives what you are asking - there is no function doing so. But this seems like an `X-Y` problem. What is the actual issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: Finally, I found it. In postgresql-15.0/src/backend/utils/adt/acl.c, convert_type_name function can do it.